# Difference between C and C++

Tags: c++, c

The code given here when compiled by g++ runs fine but gives error on compiling with gcc. Obviously, this is correct for C++ but not for C. Please help me to correct the syntax for C.

```
# include <stdio.h>
typedef struct demo
{
    int arr[20], i;
    void setvalue(int num)
    {for(i=0;i<20;i++)arr[i]=num;}

    void printvalue()
    {for(i=0;i<20;i++)printf("%d ",arr[i]);}
} example;

int main()
{
    example e;
    e.setvalue(100);
    e.printvalue();
    return 0;
}
```

Error log:

```
stov.c:7:2: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
stov.c: In function ‘main’:
stov.c:18:3: error: ‘example’ has no member named ‘setvalue’
stov.c:19:3: error: ‘example’ has no member named ‘printvalue’
```

Comment: It would be nice when asking such questions to tell us what the error is.

Comment: Is your space bar broken? And your enter-key a bit dodgy?

Comment: I didn’t downvote this but I understood those who did: C and C++ are fundamentally different, and your question makes no sense; you are essentially asking “I did X, why isn’t unrelated Y working?” Would you expect your code to work on a Pascal compiler? In JavaScript? In Haskell? Certainly not. Then why should it work in C? The common, unreasonable conflation of C and C++ is really quite tedious.

Comment: but, answering simply "C++ is not C, despite the name, and for example here C does not allow 'functions' inside struct" or similar better explanation, is more helpful. Or maybe linking to SO Qs/As that can help the OP to have a better idea about what is C++ and what is C... even suggesting to read this or that book to be enlightened... and so on. Almost everything in this case is better than a long-term downvote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have methods in C (that function in the struct). There's more than one way to solve this, but I would simply pass the object as the first argument to the function:

```
void setvalue(struct demo *d, int num)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        d->arr[i] = num;
}


/* ... */
setvalue(&e, 100);
```

Comment: you can't have methods in C++ either. (member functions)

Comment: @Cory, sure you can? member functions are one of the biggest differences between C and C++...

Comment: @bdonlan: I think Cory is being nit-picky and pointing out that in C++, methods are *called* member functions, which is a valid point, but not actually useful. :)

Comment: @Martin He's trying to convert to C (repent ? :)) ) Im C there are no references.

Comment: @Williham Totland: To be nitty picky. That's the definition of method. They may not be explicitly mention in the C++ standard as such but in the greater OO perspective they are still methods. Using the term also aids in clarity as it is a common form of reference as member function is not strict enough. You need to use the term `non static member function`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: @cnicutar: Opps.: If you are passing a pointer. don't forget the check for NULL.

Comment: @Martin: My point is; just saying "method" is, in this context, completely unambiguous and clear. There is nothing to be gained by correcting "method" to "member function".

Comment: @Martin: And do what?  You can't throw an exception, the function returns `void`, so the only alternative left is perhaps to abort the program.

Comment: @Martin, @Dietrich - And the runtime will do a fine job of aborting when you dereference a `NULL` pointer. This is a programmer error, not a user error, so if the person using your API is lazy enough to pass `NULL` to functions that clearly cannot handle `NULL`s they should expect some unfortunate results. This is the behavior of almost all functions in the C standard library and many other libraries as well. Check for `NULL` in user code (when you receive the object) rather than in every library function (which won't be able to do anything meaningful with `NULL` anyway).

Comment: @dragonwrenn - No, C has the `->` operator. It doesn't have `::`, `.*` or `->*`, but it has `->` just like it has `.`. It doesn't have the extra meanings it has in C++, but it doesn't need to.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: **Yes**. If you pass a NULL pointer into something that is expecting a pointer there is another programming error somewhere. You better `abort()` or probably more likely `assert()` the application before it does dammage (you really have no other choice).

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Unfortunately not. It may be UB but that does not mean it will crash. It just means you can't predicate what it will do. On a lot of hardware it will crash but not all. You can find several question on SO along the form of `I am de-referencing NULL and it is not crashing, how do I make it crash?`

Comment: @Martin - I don't think it's worth the processor cycles to check for `NULL` if your API states "this argument cannot be `NULL`". IMHO it's better to say "Don't pass `NULL` here" and let users risk UB than to waste time checking for an error that should only occur if the users of your API are illiterate. At best, the check should be confined to a debug build of the library, and excluded from the version that is shipped with your users' product.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: In that case use assert. It will do the check in debug code so you can make sure everything is OK. Then when you build production code you turn the check off.

Comment: @Martin - It still necessitates building two versions of a library, which is a rather clunky solution IMHO. But I guess it's what we're stuck with.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem: Your `struct` contains methods. That's no good in C.

In C++ a `struct` is mostly like a `class` (or rather, a `class` is mostly like a `struct`), and can have methods, etc.

In C, this does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

You may use function pointers in struct to emulate OOP.

```
typedef struct demo
{
  int arr[20], i;
  void (*setvalue)(int num);

  void (*printvalue)();
} example;
```

then later you can assign a function to the function pointer.

```
void set_val(int num) {for(i=0;i<20;i++)arr[i]=num;}
example_struct.setvalue = set_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that C have function-pointers and function-pointers can be used like C++ member functions, kind of. The clunky syntax can be avoided with some C preprocessor macros and templates (you can use the C preprocessor for generic programming, it's more powerful and versatile then C++ templates, give better type checking and (on modern compilers) faster and smaller code; this programming trick used to be called Code Books by Algol and COBOL programmers (I learned it during a COBOL course in my youth), but have been avoided by C programmers for some stupid reason).

Code not tested, just cobbled it together from the code in the question:

```
# include <stdio.h>
static void _setvalue(example *obj, int num)
{ int i;
  for(i=0;i<20;i++)
      obj->arr[i]=num;
}

static void _printvalue(example *obj)
{  int i;
   for(i=0;i<20;i++)
       printf("%d ", obj->arr[i]);
}


typedef struct demo
{   int arr[20], i;
    void (*const setvalue)(example *, int) = _setvalue;
    void (*const printvalue)(example *)    = _printvalue;
} example;

int main()
{   example e;
    e.setvalue(&e, 100);
    e.printvalue(&e);
    return 0;
}
```